# How to achieve alternative row color in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

How to achieve alternative row color in extjs 5 grid. As i know we have to apply x-grid-row-alt class in css to achieve this. Its working in extjs 4 but not in Extjs 5. Any Ideas on this?

Comment: Showing what you've tried is recommended on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getRowClass` method in `viewConfig` of your grid.

```
viewConfig: {
  getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams)
  {
     return (index % 2 == 0) ? 'grid-row1' : 'grid-row2';
  }
},
```

CSS

```
tr.grid-row1 td{
    background-color: #d6f0f9;
}
tr.grid-row2 td{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/1353/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`stripeRows`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-cfg-stripeRows) (set it on the `viewConfig` of the grid):

> True to stripe the rows.
>
> This causes the CSS class `x-grid-row-alt` to be added to alternate rows
>   of the grid. A default CSS rule is provided which sets a background
>   color, but you can override this with a rule which either overrides
>   the background-color style using the !important modifier, or which
>   uses a CSS selector of higher specificity.

If you want to customize it try using `x-grid-item-alt` instead (it's the default of [`altRowCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-property-altRowCls)).

You can also change the scss background color variable [`$grid-row-cell-alt-background-color`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-css_var-S-grid-row-cell-alt-background-color).